# Giving an example of an undefinable family relationship

Tags: logic

I'm trying to solve the below problem.

> Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the vocabulary consisting of a binary relation $P$ and an unary relation $F$. Interpret $P(x,y)$ as "$x$ is a parent of $y$" and $F(x,y)$ as "$x$ is female". Give an example of a family relationship that cannot be defined by a $\mathcal{V}$-formula.

At the top of my head I can't really come up with anything that shouldn't be possible to describe using parenthood and sex. I mean, everyone has a sex and parents. Shouldn't every family relationship be explicable using those properties only?

Is there any other fundamental property that we posses that I'm not seeing, or am I misinterpreting the question a bit here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this depends on what counts as a "family relationship".

Two suggestions:

(1) $x$ and $y$ are married. This is just totally unrelated to $P$ and $F$.

(2) $x$ is an ancestor of $y$. This concept can be explained using $P$, but it's not definable from $P$ by a first-order formula.

Comment: Yeah, I also think that half-siblings could be something.

Comment: @OskarTegby In a comment to your now deleted answer, you wrote "I feel like it would be useless to ask a question about family relationships when being married is in a completely different category, and being an ancestor isn't really a family relationship." I think of spouse and ancestor / descendant as family relationships. You may disagree. What we can agree on is that "family relationship" isn't clearly defined, which makes the question quite imprecise.

Comment: I just feel like there's no mathematical value in asking that question if that's the answer. Like, what did I learn by pondering that question if that's the answer?

Comment: @OskarTegby "What's the mathematical value" is probably a question best asked to whoever suggested you ponder this question! Maybe the idea was to get the point across that which relations are definable depends on which relations you take as primitive. The fact that "$x$ is an ancestor of $y$" is not first-order definable is also kind of interesting: the proof uses the compactness theorem! In any case, I don't like the question either - I think there are better ways to make this point.

Comment: Agreed. How do you mean that the compactness theorem would show that? Isn't every subset of that satisfiable? Also, couldn't we just use $P(x,y)$ to describe their family relationship?

Comment: Let $\varphi_n(x,y)$ be the formula $\exists z_0\dots\exists z_n ((x = z_0)\land (y = z_n) \land \bigwedge_{i=0}^{n-1} P(z_i,z_{i+1})$. Then $\varphi_1(x,y)$ says that $x$ is a parent of $y$, $\varphi_2(x,y)$ says that $x$ is a grandparent of $y$, $\varphi_3(x,y)$ says that $x$ is a great-grandparent of $y$, etc. Then $x$ is an ancestor of $y$ if and only if there is some $n$ such that $\varphi_n(x,y)$. But $\bigvee_{n\geq 1} \varphi_n(x,y)$ is not a first-order formula, since that's an infinite disjunction.

Comment: That's probably what they were going for then. I'll ask the professor next time I get the chance.

Comment: @OskarTegby Now suppose for contradiction that there's some other crazy first-order formula $\psi(x,y)$ which happens to define the relation "$x$ is an ancestor of $y$". Write down the set of formulas $\{\psi(x,y)\}\cup \{\lnot \varphi_n(x,y)\mid n\geq 1\}$. Any finite subset is consistent, since you can draw a family tree in which $x$ is an ancestor of $y$ which is $>n$ generations removed from $y$ for any $n$. By compactness the whole set is consistent. But then we have $a$ and $b$ such that $\psi(a,b)$ is true, but $a$ is not an ancestor of $b$, contradiction.